# Multiple Instances and Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

In my scenario, I have two servers in each of them two SQL Server instances:

- Server 1: Instance 1 and Instance 2
- Server 2: Instance 1 and Instance 2

I created availability groups between the instances like this:

- Instance 1 from Server 1 with Instance 1 from Server 2: Availability Group 1
- Instance 2 from Server 1 with Instance 2 from Server 2: Availability Group 2

And I have create a two listeners:

- Listener 1, for Availability Group 1
- Listener 2, for Availability Group 2

The problem is when I try to connect with the Listener 1, it connects me to the Availability Group 1, but when I try with Listener 2 it also connects me to Availability Group 1, not to Availability Group 2.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to ad some details about your network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**This can happen due to the TCP ports configuration of your instances and listeners**

> If one of the instances of SQL Server is already listening on TCP port
>   1433 via the instance listener and there are no other services
>   (including additional instances of SQL Server) on the computer
>   listening on port 1433, this will not cause a port conflict with the
>   availability group listener. This is because the availability group
>   listener can share the same TCP port inside the same service process.
>   However multiple instances of SQL Server (side-by-side) should not be
>   configured to listen on the same port.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017#SelectListenerPort)

In short, you can have both your listeners listening on port **1433**, as long as you change the tcp ports for the instances to different ports like **1533**, **1633**.

You could also use different port numbers than **1433** but then you need to specify these in the connection string(s).

In the case of "**one instance, one listener**" you could be using the same port for both.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is your port configuration. At least one instance on each server will be running on a non-standard port (something other than 1433) but if both of your listeners were configured with the default configuration, they will be listening on port 1433. This causes a port conflict and whichever SQL instance started first and started listening on that port is the one that will respond to connections.

From your description, I would surmise that Instance 1 on both servers is listening on port 1433 and both listeners are as well. When you connect via either listener name, it connects on port 1433 which is Instance 1 in both cases, because you cannot share ports across instances of SQL Server.

To resolve this problem, first, you should configure your SQL Server instances to use non-default ports ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-2017)). Finally, you should reconfigure your Listeners to use different ports ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017)). Your listener ports can be the same as your instance ports, but they cannot conflict with other instances or listeners on the same server. So Listener 1 can use the same port as Instance 1 but must be different from Instance 2 and Listener 2.

Note that when you use non-default ports, you need to specify the port number in your connection string - `Server=tcp:Listener1,1456;Database=MyDB;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI`